# Naming APIs that differ only by authentication scheme

Tags: rest, authentication, restful-authentication

I have a service that is exposed to two kinds of users, which use different authentication mechanisms. (One uses AAD, and another uses some other in-house authentication scheme)

I thought the best course of action would be to create two endpoints (Although their internal logic is the same), each serving one type of users.

Is there some convention on how to differentiate the urls of these two endpoints? (e.g. {EndpointBase}{AuthType})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the implementation of authentication in Dot Net, it appears to me that having numerous authentication schemes running in parallel is a common practice, and that the system was designed especially for that:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.2#why-would-i-want-multiple-handlers-for-a-requirement

So it appears that the system is designed to support two authentications for a single endpoint.